# LispWorks on Windows 7 won't load Quicklisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, lispworks

I'm using LispWorks Personal Edition and have only been able to load Quicklisp by loading the file rather than through the initialization file, `.lispworks`, which LispWorks is supposed to find in my home directory, `C:\Users\Me\`. Am I placing the initialization file in the wrong directory? Or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Personal Edition does not load any initialization file. This is clearly stated in the documentation.

The limitations of the LispWorks Personal Edition are described here: http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html

Comment: That would include the sitelisp init file as well?

Comment: However, take a look at [Using LispWorks Personal with Emacs/SLIME on Windows](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/040315.html).